# corrupted encoding of html message

Tags: python, html, dataframe, encoding, simplehttpserver

I am building a simple server which responds to a GET request and sends html which contains table of utf-8 values.
The table is created from json object by using pandas DataFrame and to_html method

The server is based on BaseHTTPRequestHandler class (http.server module)

When I send a GET request from the Chrome browser, I receive gibberish text values

I tried to add the charset tag to the header using either

```
self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
or
self.send_header('charset','utf-8')
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztm3Q.png)

My code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from sys import argv

BIND_HOST = 'localhost'
PORT_HOST = 8000

input = {0: {'יעד': 'באר שבע מרכז', 'זמן הגעה': '17:38:00', 'רציף': '1'}, 1: {'יעד': 'ראש העין צפון', 'זמן הגעה': '17:48:00', 'רציף': '2'}}

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

     def do_GET(self):
        try:
            output = pd.DataFrame(input).transpose().to_html()
            print(output)
            self.write_response(bytes(output))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

     def write_response(self, content):
 #      self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
 #      self.send_header('charset','utf-8')
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        print(content.encode('utf-8'))
        self.wfile.write(content.encode(encoding='utf-8'))


if len(argv) > 1:
    arg = argv[1].split(':')
    BIND_HOST = arg[0]
    PORT_HOST = int(arg[1])

httpd = HTTPServer((BIND_HOST, PORT_HOST), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
print(f'Listening on http://{BIND_HOST}:{PORT_HOST}\n')
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: What is `pd` in your code? Could you post a minimal reproducible example we can all run?

Comment: pd for pandas, adding my code in the original question

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the content-type header.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from sys import argv

BIND_HOST = 'localhost'
PORT_HOST = 8000

input = {0: {'יעד': 'באר שבע מרכז', 'זמן הגעה': '17:38:00', 'רציף': '1'}, 1: {'יעד': 'ראש העין צפון', 'זמן הגעה': '17:48:00', 'רציף': '2'}}

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

     def do_GET(self):
        output = pd.DataFrame(input).transpose().to_html()
        self.write_response(output.encode('utf-8'))

     def write_response(self, content):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(content)


if len(argv) > 1:
    arg = argv[1].split(':')
    BIND_HOST = arg[0]
    PORT_HOST = int(arg[1])

httpd = HTTPServer((BIND_HOST, PORT_HOST), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
print(f'Listening on http://{BIND_HOST}:{PORT_HOST}\n')
httpd.serve_forever()
```